# How to detach a Solaris non-global zone when zoneadm detach is not available?

Tags: solaris, containers

I have an old Solaris 10U1 that does not have `zoneadm detach` command. Only the following subcommands are supported:

- help
- boot
- halt
- ready
- reboot
- list
- verify
- install
- uninstall

I need this to move the zones to a Solaris10U9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to detach. Just make a backup of your zone root, copy/move it to your new global zone and do an upgrade on attach (zoneadm attach -u) with it.

Detaching is zone a convenience but not mandatory. This is clearly stated in the [zoneadm manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/zoneadm-1m.html).

*Therefore, it is advised (though not required) that the detach subcommand should be run before the “attach” takes place.*

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check if there isn't a patch (or patchset) available that sufficiently updates the zones technology and adds the functionality you need.

I'd also suggest that you put in a software problem report with Oracle to ask this very question.  Oracle probably has an answer for you.

Comment: No need to call support when this is already documented in the manual page.